# Detecting image location of the picture in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am working on a camera app in which the pictures I take should store the location as to where they were taken. So maybe after a while, if I want to know where a particular picture was taken, I should click on a button, say above my photo album, which should re-direct me to a mapview. There, it should show the places where i've taken all my pictures, with an album for each place.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Add **MetaData** to **UIImage**. Same metadata of UIImage can be used to know images's location.

Refer [Save_Photo_to_Album_with_Metadata](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/Media/Video_and_Photos/Save_Photo_to_Album_with_Metadata)

Comment: What frameworks do i have to import to use this feature? Also where i have to enter the codes for the GPS, in viewDidLoad part?